# Pagination codeigniter with query search

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

i want to create codeigniter pagination in my search form, when i clicked submit,it successfully shows the query search but when i clicked the number page link or next page, it shows message "undefined variable rec" and "Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object" ,i'm sure the query has been passed to variable $rec.

And i see the problem here when i change the page,the variable return to null, so variable $rec didn't get the value from 'post'.

my question: how do i keep the value from 'post' so the query will get the variable value when i change the page?

here is my controller:

```
public function search(){

$kat=$this->input->post('kategori');
$prov=$this->input->post('prov');
$kot=$this->input->post('kota');


if($kat=='' && $prov!='' && $kot!=''){
$rec=$this->db->query("select * from showall where id_prov='$prov' and id_kota='$kot' ");
}
else if($kot=='' && $kat!='' && $prov!=''){
$rec=$this->db->query("select * from showall where id_kat='$kat' and id_prov='$prov' ");
}
else if($kat=='' && $kot=='' && $prov!=''){
$rec=$this->db->query("select * from showall where id_prov='$prov' ");
}
else if($kat!='' && $prov=='' && $kot==''){
$rec=$this->db->query("select * from showall where id_kat='$kat' ");
}
else if($kat!='' && $prov!='' && $kot!=''){
$rec=$this->db->query("select * from showall where id_kat='$kat' and id_prov='$prov' and id_kota='$kot' ");
}

$dat=$rec;
$data['count']=$dat->num_rows();
  if($data['count'] >0){
  $data['db']=$rec;
$config['total_rows'] = $data['db']->num_rows(); 

$config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/lowongan/cari';

$config['per_page'] = 1;    
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$data['paging'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
if($kat=='' && $prov!='' && $kot!=''){
$d = $this->db->get_where('showall',array('id_prov'=>$prov,'id_kota'=>$kot) ,$config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
}
else if($kot=='' && $kat!='' && $prov!=''){
$d= $this->db->get_where('showall',array('id_kat'=>$kat,'id_prov'=>$prov) ,$config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
}
else if($kat=='' && $kot=='' && $prov!=''){
$d = $this->db->get_where('showall',array('id_prov'=>$prov) ,$config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
}
 if($kat!='' && $prov=='' && $kot==''){
$d = $this->db->get_where('showall',array('id_kat'=>$kat) ,$config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
}
else if($kat!='' && $prov!='' && $kot!=''){
$d = $this->db->get_where('showall',array('id_kat'=>$kat,'id_prov'=>$prov,'id_kota'=>$kot) ,$config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
}

$data['record']=$d;
$data1['kat']=$this->query->kategoriAll();
$data1['prov']=$this->query->showProv();
$data['q1']=$this->query->lokasi();
$data['q2']=$this->query->perusahaan();
$data['q3']=$this->query->kategori();

$this->load->view("user/head");
$this->load->view("user/bar",$data1);   
$this->load->view( 'user/hal_cari',$data);
$this->load->view("user/footer");
}
else{
$data1['kat']=$this->query->kategoriAll();
$data1['prov']=$this->query->showProv();
$data['q1']=$this->query->lokasi();
$data['q2']=$this->query->perusahaan();
$data['q3']=$this->query->kategori();

$this->load->view("user/head");
$this->load->view("user/bar",$data1);   
$this->load->view( 'user/kosong',$data);
$this->load->view("user/footer");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the condition array in the URL using assoc_to_uri(). I am doing like below.

```
    $this->load->model('classified_model','classified');
    $ClassifiedList = $this->classified->searchPage($condition,'classified_view',$perPage,$page*$perPage);
    $uriString = $this->uri->assoc_to_uri($condition);
    $config['uri_segment'] = count($condition) * 2 + 4;
    $base_url = site_url('classified/search/' . $uriString . '/page/');
    $base_url = preg_replace("/\.[a-z]*$/","", $base_url);
    $config['base_url'] = $base_url;
    $config['per_page'] = 1;
```

To get the $condition from uri again use

```
   $condition = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc();
```

Comment: You could also generate code for search with pagination and for other CRUD actions at thephpcode.com. Need to add modules for each table then can add fields and actions for functions.

Comment: $condition is an array containing the column and value for the field. Please let me know which step you didn't understand. searchPage is a method in my model.

Comment: then how do i get the variable value in my query from URI?

Comment: $condition = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(); will generate the array back

Comment: see the example of the functions in help http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: what is $config['uri_segment'] = count($condition) * 2 + 4; ?

Comment: Pagination library needs to know where the page number exists in the uri to highlight the current page.